# update multiple rows in a table for selected ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'table1' which needs to be updated.
I have a query that will extract the required id which needs to be updated.
e.g.

```
+------+
| id     |
+------+
|    2   |
+------+
|    3   |
+------+
|    4   |
+------+
|    7   |
+------+
|    8   |
+------+
```

I tried

```
UPDATE table1 set col1=0 where id=**query that lists id**  [Didn't worked]
UPDATE table1 set col1=0 where id in **query that lists id**  [Didn't worked]
```

How can I update the table for the number of ids, that I have extracted from another query?

*Note:
Using MySQL

Also the subquery from which I have extracted the ids involves 'table1' and from [mysql document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
It says,
Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the most efficient way is probably to use `join`:

```
UPDATE table1 toupdate join
       (select id
        from <someothertable>
       ) sot
       on toupdate.id = sot.id
    set toupdate.col1 = 0;
```

This will also work if the query that selects the `id`s actually uses `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
update table1 set col1 = 0 where id in (select id from tablen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
UPDATE table1 set col1=0 where id in (select id from <someothertable>)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked was as follows:

1. CREATE TABLE ids_table AS (SOME-QUERY-HERE-THAT-WILL-SPIT-REQD-IDS);
2. UPDATE table1 SET col1=0 where id in (SELECT id from ids_table);
3. DROP TABLE ids_table;

The idea doesn't might seem a good practice but it worked.